# Does not apply styles after dynamically adding content by ajax

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

If you would need a code - i will post it, but it seems problem is not in code.

I made menu. After clicking on menu - submenu is donwloaded. After this i am change CSS to applay new styles for open section and its downloaded submenu. BUT THIS CSS DO NOT WORK. If i copy this dynamic content after adding from in the inspactor windows and paste as html directly with changed CSS as new part of menu - this new part after refreshing the page works without problem apllying all styles. If i make javascript changing CSS after dynamic adding of content - new style do not work. He can be changed without problem by setAttribute - but do not work (as i said earlier - code is good, because after copy-pasting this section after refreshing the page all styles work good . Where can i find mistake?

part of code

```
 document.getElementById("menu_item_1235").parentNode.setAttribute("class", "adm-sub-submenu-block adm-sub-submenu-open");


 var xmlDoc = http_request.responseXML;
 var nodeLength = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("child");
 for (var i = 0; i < nodeLength.length; i++) { 

document.getElementById("menu_item_1235").nextSibling.appendChild(document.importNode(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("child")[i].childNodes[0], true));

}
```

screen shots:

i.stack.imgur.com/1Haxs.png
i.stack.imgur.com/3zbxX.png

also when i make this way CSS works partly

```
var string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(nodeLength[0].childNodes[0]);
document.getElementById("menu_item_1236").nextSibling.innerHTML = string;
document.getElementById("menu_item_1236").parentNode.setAttribute("class", "adm-sub-submenu-block adm-sub-submenu-open");
```

Only part of section is highlighted:

[image]

Comment: You got it, javascript sets inline styles on the elements currently available, not on any future elements added later.

Comment: `"it seems problem is not in code"` - Are you suggesting that your code must be correct and that the problem must be the web browser?  Good luck with that.

Comment: can you describe a bit more? it is possible to do in my situation? i aplly NEW CSS rule after adding new content - do not work. I apply NEW CSS rule before downloadig new content - also nothing work. Me style is not inline style - my style for this section is in CSS section. class="old_style" i change on class="new_style". For example. if i make the same menu but only with hidden submenu - after changind class - menu opens.

Comment: David, i wrote - if i copy this section of HTML after uploading by ajax - and paste in HTML as new section of menu - all works fine with new style

Answer (score 0):

How do you add your content from the ajax request? Maybe your ajax-content is read as Text and not parsed into the dom, so no CSS will be applied.

Comment: look on my screenshots all sections are identical. Second is added by ajax - all other html http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Haxs.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/3zbxX.png

Comment: i enter new divs by ImportNode in child section

Answer (score 0):

In order to identify mistakes, we will require the code. However, you can try to add class on Ajax success as follows. This may save your time:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/sample.php",
 type: "GET",
 data: "request=somedata",
 success: function(e){
  $(".submenu").html(e);
  $(".submenu").addClass("submenu_class");
 }
});
```

Comment: it is hard for me to work with query. I write pure javascript to practice

Comment: @user3802440 Well, do you use firebug console of firefox? If not, try it. If you have certain type of errors after ajax (or anywhere else), firebug would show you as the code runs.

Comment: no errors. all works, content are downloaded, tags all are correct. Problem only that new style is not apllied. No errors in error window